# Is there a proper name for instance of struct?

Tags: c++, struct

Instances of classes are called objects, but is there a certain name for instances of structs?

Having the separate terms "class" and "object" is useful to distinguish between the class and the instance of the class, but I've only ever heard of the single term "struct" to refer to either the struct or the instance of the struct (depending on context).

Comment: They are the same thing.  A `class` is a `struct` where the default access modifier is `private` instead of `public`.  That means they make objects

Comment: Instances of structs are still objects

Comment: Thanks. I knew the difference between class and struct, but didn't realize that an instance of either are both called objects.

Comment: I usually call 'class instance' and 'struct instance.' haha...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instances of structs, classes, ints, unions, floats etc. are all objects.

Comment: More information is at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object. The standard, when it needs to be more precise, says “object of class type” or similar. Structs, classes, and even unions and lambdas are class types; functions, ints, arrays, pointers, etc. aren’t.

Comment: @DanielH , functions are  very specials because they are not objects, while ints are (objects of fundamental type not of class type).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I think references are technically not objects either. However, references and functions still both have types. The full type hierarchy seems to be [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Type_classification).

Comment: cppreference is not the reference about the language. Standard says that except references and functions every thing else is an object.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between `struct` and `class` is the default access when you declare a class (whether you use `struct` or `class`, what you declare is a class!). This two:

```
struct Foo : private Bar { private: int x; };
class Foo : Bar { int x; };
```

as well as this two:

```
struct Foo : Bar { int x; };
class Foo : public Bar { public: int x; };
```

are equivalent. Having an object there is no way to tell from that object, whether the class was declared using the keyword `struct` or `class`.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class) on the type trait `is_class`:

> Note that types declared with the struct keyword are classes, so this
>   trait is true for "structs".

And [the docs on type classification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Type_classification) have this enumeration:

> Types are grouped in various categories based on their properties:
>
> - object type is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not void type (see also
>     std::is_object);
> - scalar types are [...]
> - trivial types [...]

**TL;DR**

C++ does not have structs and classes, but only classes.

Or... if you are fine with a little bit of misleading terminology: Instances of structs and classes are both objects.